# Is there a shortcut Key to open the Current Windows Notification?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, notifications

On the new windows, you have the notifications that show up in the bottom right.  So when a new email comes in or a slack notification comes in, is there a windows shortcut key to open that notification other than just clicking on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press WINDOWS+V once to select the notification and then you can open it by pressing ENTER.
For more information about shortcuts in Windows: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

Windows changed the shortcut, it is now

<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

to "Select a notification" or "Set focus to a notification"